# How to make multidex enabled on an Android project in Eclipse WITHOUT Gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, firebase, android-multidex

I am building an Android application using Eclipse without `Gradle`. Whenever I run the application the following error occurs -

> 01-12 15:31:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(8125):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string; 01-12 15:31:49.874:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8125):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaj.(Unknown Source)
>   01-12 15:31:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(8125):   at
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source) 01-12
>   15:31:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(8125):     at
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)

I think the error is because `Multidex` is not enabled. How can I enable it without `gradle`? Also any other possible reason for this error to come? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When using Eclipse ADT for MultiDex, you can to build your application with either Maven as well.

To Activate MultiDex using android-maven-plugin follow this http://docs.repro.io/en/dev/sdk/getstarted/android-multidex.html#android-maven-pluginmultidex

You need to Add below snippet inside `<project><build><plugins>` tag in your pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.0</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <sdk>
          <platform>23</platform>
          <path>${user.home}/Library/Android/sdk</path>
        </sdk>
        <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
        <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
        <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
        <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
        <dex>
          <multi-dex>true</multi-dex>
        </dex>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```